# IBM Bluemix Cloud Foundry SpringBoot kotlin app error

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have deploy on IBM Bluemix a spring boot application written in kotlin. I have use liberty for java.

But I cant able to run correctly my app, but on my machine in local it work very well.

When I call my REST API  it return me an error or not work.

This is the error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500). java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   it.gate42.skip.DeviceInfo.DeviceInfo_Accessor_ewee6w (initialization
>   failure)

I have already tried to change the Java version but the error is the same.
(I have set OPEN_JDK and version 1.8.+)

This is the log of call that return me the cloud foundry app: https://gist.github.com/paranoiasystem/a28a2587c231f2b398c4650ba1c7016c

I have post it on gist because is so long and it is impossible to post all log here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue, I have rewrite my manifest.yml like this:

```
---
applications:
- name: testskipapi
  memory: 1G
  instances: 1
  path: build/libs/skipcode-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git
env:
  JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE: '{ jre: { version: 1.8.0_+ } }'
```

Comment: 1.) You can remove the OpenJDK version because it will default to what you have (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/config/open_jdk_jre.yml#L20)  2.) You don't want to use the buildpack URL that you have set.  It's pointing to the master branch of the buildpack where all the new commits land.  You want to point to a specific release so it's stable.  Use `https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git#v4.5.2` to use the latest at the time of writing (or insert your version of choice).  Alternatively, you can use the platform provided buildpack.  See `cf buildpacks`.